# PHP Join Query for Three Table When There is No Direct Common Column?

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join

I have Three Tables in which first two tables have common column to match the record, and 2nd and third table also have common column **but there is no direct matching column in first and third table**. How shall I write join query ?

1. Table1(**order**) Column Names are `order_id, patient_id, total, discount`
2. Table2 (**order_details**) Column Names are `order_details_id, order_id, test_id, result`
3. Table3(**tests**) Column Names are `test_id, test_name, test_normal_value`

Comment: Note that `order` is a reserved word, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: You can have multiple join statements. Just join `order` to `order_details` and then `order_details` to `tests`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it helps

```
SELECT * FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN `order_details` ON `order`.`order_id` = `order_details`.`order_id`
LEFT JOIN `tests` ON `order_details`.`test_id` = `test`.`test_id`
```

Comment: bro I want to get on the basis of order_id of first table

Comment: Then add the "WHERE `order`.`order_id` = " statement

Comment: @MateeGojra You have a tick under the vote count, to the left from the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT a.patient_id FROM table1 as a 
LEFT JOIN table2 as b on a.order_id = b.order_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 as c on c.test_id = b.test_id";
```

to join this 3  table in one query, we need to assign each table a name. For example table1 AS NewNameTable1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS NewNameTable2. To connecting between this 3 table we need to have a foreign key for each table. So that this 3 table able to JOIN and we able to fetch the data in single query. As long this 3 table is JOINED via foreign key, you can echo out any attribute from any table that Joined.

Comment: its not about getting data of patient its about getting order data

Comment: then u change a.patient_id to others attribute.. SELECT b.order_id

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: done explaination. hope it can help abit to understand it. correct me if iam wrong